# A dance between numbers

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, number-property

Given the following equation:

$$\Delta = \Biggl(\frac{t \mod 6}{(t \mod r) + 1}\Biggr)^2$$

Find the relationship between $t$ and $r$, along with the properties of each, that ensures $\Delta = 9$. For clarity, the correct answer is **not** looking for values that ensure $\Delta = 9$, but rather an explanation on how one could determine if a given value for $r$ is valid with respect to a given value for $t$ and vice-versa.

---

<sub>*This puzzle focuses on the relationship used to build [my previous puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112144/the-maze-of-everlasting-flowers). I felt as though it was nice enough to be shared since it wasn't exposed with the original puzzle.*</sub>

Comment: Wow, thanks for the bounty - there was no need to give that! My answer wasn't *that* comprehensive... Thank you anyway though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is that:

> $t$ is any number of the form $3(2k+1)$ for integer $k$, i.e. $t\in\{3,9,15,...\}$, and $r$ is any number that divides $t$

See this as follows (assuming $t$ and $r$ are positive integers):

> $\Delta=9$ implies:
>  $$\Biggl(\frac{t \mod 6}{(t \mod r) + 1}\Biggr)^2=9$$
>  $$\therefore \Biggl(\frac{t \mod 6}{(t \mod r) + 1}\Biggr)=3$$
>  $$\therefore t \mod 6=3(t \mod r)+3$$
>  Now write $t=6k+j$, for $j\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ and integer $k$, and similarly $t=rm+n$ for $n\in\{0,1,2,3,...,m-1\}$ and integer $m$
>
>  Therefore we have:
>  $$j=3n+3$$
>  Now the only possible solution of this is $n=0$ ($n=1$ or greater would imply $j>5$ which is impossible by construction), therefore we have:
>  $$j=3$$
>  Therefore:
>  $$t=6k+3=3(2k+1)$$
>  and $t=rm$ for integer $m$ which is what we wanted to show.

Thus the first few options for $t$ and $r$ are as follows:

> $t=3$ and $r\in\{1,3\}$
>
>  $t=9$ and $r\in\{1,3,9\}$
>
>  $t=15$ and $r\in\{1,3,5,15\}$
>
>  $t=21$ and $r\in\{1,3,7,21\}$
>
>  $t=27$ and $r\in\{1,3,9,27\}$
>
>  $t=33$ and $r\in\{1,3,11,33\}$
>
>  $t=39$ and $r\in\{1,3,13,39\}$
>
>  $t=45$ and $r\in\{1,3,5,9,15,45\}$
>  *etc.*

So, finally to explicitly answer the question:

> The relationship between $t$ and $r$ is that $t$ is a multiple of $r$.
>
>  If given any $t$, if and only if it can be written as $t=6k+3$ can it be a part of a $(t,r)$ pair, in which case any $r$ that divides it will work.
>
>  If given any $r$, it can be part of a $(t,r)$ pair if and only if it is odd
> - If it is even it cannot be a divisor of the odd number $3(2k+1)$
> - If it is odd, then a possible $(t,r)$ pair is $(t=3r,r)$.

Comment: I love this answer overall; but I *especially* love the fact that you *demonstrated* the relationship using the first few values of $t$. It clearly shows that [ROT13](https://rot13.com/)(gur bayl inyvq inyhrf sbe e, tvira n inyhr sbe g ner gur snpgbef bs g). Based on timing, I must give the check to TCooper's answer, but I intend to award a bounty to yours due to the effort you've given and details you've included.

Comment: @Tacoタコス I think it more correct enough to deserve the check > a few minutes difference in answer time - and mine has technical inaccuracies in the wording

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how to show my work/explain this, it's mostly intuitive, but

> delta = 9 where *t* mod 6 = 3 and *t* mod *r* = 0

> So we know *t* must be a multiple of 3 but not 6 and a multiple of *r*

> so I guess I can best simplify it as `t=nr` where `t mod 6 = 3` and `n >= 1`

In this answer I'm implying the requirements of *r* based on its relation to *t* - Anon's answer is a far superior explanation

Comment: @Anon correct, I misread it the first go around, apologies TCooper!

Comment: I didn't see @TCooper's answer pop up while I was writing mine. Nevertheless I'll leave mine up (for the time being at least) as it goes into more detail on the derivation, and how to determine which pairs $(t,r)$ work

Comment: @Anon please do leave yours up - it's a much better explanation. I feel like half (or more of) this puzzle was breaking it down clearly rather than the "challenge" of the equation

Comment: @Tacoタコス No worries, just shows why we need Anon's answer to clarify ;)